# I am attempting to write a numpy array to a txt file and then read the file back to a numpy array

Tags: numpy

I am attempting to write a numpy array to a txt file and then read the file back to a numpy array.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import asarray
from numpy import savetxt
##import csv
##import numpy
a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

with open(r'test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(" ".join(map(str, a)))

array = np.loadtxt(fname = "test.txt")
print(leafref)
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/MyPC/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/numpytocsv.py", line 12, in <module>
    array = np.loadtxt(fname = "test.txt")
  File "C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 926, in loadtxt
    fh = np.lib._datasource.open(fname, 'rt', encoding=encoding)
  File "C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\_datasource.py", line 260, in open
    return ds.open(path, mode, encoding=encoding, newline=newline)
  File "C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\_datasource.py", line 608, in open
    found = self._findfile(path)
  File "C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\_datasource.py", line 446, in _findfile
    if self.exists(name):
  File "C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\_datasource.py", line 544, in exists
    from urllib.request import urlopen
  File "C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 84, in <module>
    import base64
  File "C:/Users/MyPC/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36\base64.py", line 3, in <module>
    str = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())
AttributeError: module 'base64' has no attribute 'b64encode'
```

Comment: try loadtext with `,delimiter=' '` ? No obvious reason to call bhase64 if the saved format is valid

Answer (score 1):

```
In [84]: a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]) 
    ...:  
    ...: with open(r'test.txt', 'w') as f: 
    ...:     f.write(" ".join(map(str, a))) 
    ...:                                                                        
In [85]: cat test.txt                                                           
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

In [86]: np.loadtxt('test.txt')                                                 
Out[86]: array([0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.])
```

alternative saves:

```
In [87]: np.savetxt('test.txt', a, delimiter=',')                               
In [88]: cat test.txt                                                           
0.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00
2.000000000000000000e+00
3.000000000000000000e+00
4.000000000000000000e+00
5.000000000000000000e+00
6.000000000000000000e+00
7.000000000000000000e+00
8.000000000000000000e+00
9.000000000000000000e+00
In [89]: np.savetxt('test.txt', a, delimiter=',', fmt='%6d')                    
In [90]: cat test.txt                                                           
     0
     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
     6
     7
     8
     9
In [91]: np.loadtxt('test.txt')                                                 
Out[91]: array([0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.])
```

save a 2d array (one row):

```
In [92]: np.savetxt('test.txt', a[None,:], delimiter=',', fmt='%6d')            

In [94]: cat test.txt                                                           
     0,     1,     2,     3,     4,     5,     6,     7,     8,     9
In [96]: np.loadtxt('test.txt',delimiter=',')                                   
Out[96]: array([0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.])
```